# Xcode fails to build unreal engine 4 project

Tags: c++, macos, xcode7, unreal-engine4

So I'm trying to make a game using Unreal Engine 4 but I'm running into some issues.
Up until now I've been working on the Unreal Engine Editor only and it's been working just fine but when I started creating C++ classes and using Xcode as well, after trying to build it fails with an exit code 5 error. However that error is coming from the building of the editor itself, I have no idea how to make it only build my project and not the editor from the source.

Also, when i try to compile it from the Editor, it fails with an error saying that it failed to produce item :/Users...../UE4Editor.dylib

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

```
If you have source control, you can do this.
```

1. **BACK THIS UP**

2. Roll back to a working copy.
3. Delete

   `/.vs
   /Build
   /Binaries
   /DerivedDataCache
   /Intermediate
   /Saved
   .xcode file
   .db file`
4. Click on the .uproject file, it will say to rebuild it. Press yes.
5. Open Unreal Engine
6. Right Click the .uproject file >> Services >> Generate XCode Project
7. Make your game :D